# Asus Eee PC R101d videos don't play properly in Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: graphics, video, intel, playback

I installed Lubuntu 12.10 on an Asus Eee PC R101D (Intel Atom N450, Intel GMA 3150). And there is a problem with video playback. It won't play videos properly, only stuttering, extremely slow, hanging. When it still had Windows 7 Starter on it, the very same videos played smoothly. Is there a fix for this?